# Calling a servlet from a dynamically generated form

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I'm making a mock up of an online store for school. I'm storing my products in an SQL Database. I want to display all products in the DB with buttons next to them that will send their ID to the cart_servlet. In order to display the products I'm generating a table like so:

```
public static String getInventory(){
    String result = "<table>";
    for ( Product p : DAO_Product.getProducts() ) {
        result = result + "<tr>"
                + "<td>" + p.getName() + "</td>"
                + "<td><img src=\"resources/images/" + p.getImage() + "\" alt=\"Duke waving his hand\"></td>"
                + "<td>" + p.getDollars() + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + p.getPennies() + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + p.getStock() + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + p.getDescription() + "</td>"

                //creates a form consisting of one button and a hidden value
                //clicking the button should submit the corresponding hidden value
                + "<td><form action=\"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cart_servlet\" method=\"post\">"
                + "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"product\" value=\"" + p.getId() + "\" />"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Add to Cart\" />"
                + "</form>"
                //End Form

                + "</tr>";
    }
}
```

This creates the correct table as I envisioned and the HTML it generates looks correct:

[image: output form]

```
<table><tr><td>Caverna</td>
    <td><img src="resources/images/caverna.jpg" alt="sampleImage"></td>
    <td>112</td><td>12</td><td>34</td>
    <td> you are the bearded leader of a small dwarf family which lives in a little cave in the mountains. Together, you</td>

<td><form action ="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cart_servlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
</form>
```

However when I click the button I am presented with: 'HTTP Status 404 - Not Found' description: 'The requested resource is not available'

The Servlet I am requesting is my 'CartServlet':

```
@WebServlet( "/cart_servlet" )
public class CartServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String result;
    Status status = new Status();
    req.setAttribute( "status", status );
    //RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher( "browseProducts.jsp" );
    if ( req.getParameter( "submit" ) != null ) {
    }
    //view.forward( req, resp );
    }
}
```

I've commenting out everything in my 'CartServlet' and I am sure that it probably cant get the context somehow or find the class but I am unsure about how to fix this.

Comment: Check ${pageContext.request.contextPath} for once, make sure it gives you the path you are looking for. I think thats causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I verified the path was correct and looked to other solutions. I found out I should be using the JSTL library to create my table as apposed to injecting HTML. The way I was doing it before wouldn't run my code. I provided an answer with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was approaching this all wrong. Instead I should have built the table within my JSP using JSTL. With the following code I was able to delete 'getInventory()':

The First step is to add the following line to the top of your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

**Note** Ensure you have downloaded the JSTL library and added it to your project. You can find it [here](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar).

The Second step is to declare any variables you would need. In this case I require an ArrayList of 'Products':

```
<%
    ArrayList<Product> products = DAO_Product.getProducts();
    //Set an attribute to reference our Arraylist
    pageContext.setAttribute( "products", products );
 %>
```

Now we are ready to build our table. The table will display information about each product and have a button in the last column that will call 'cart_servlet'. We are going to use the 'forEach' from 'JSTL':

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" >
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Add to Cart?</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="p" items="${products}" >
        <tr>
            <td>${p.name}</td>
            <td><img src="resources/images/${p.getImage()}" alt="Cool Pic"></td>
            <td>$${p.dollars}.${p.pennies}</td>
            <td>${p.description}</td>
            <td>${p.stock}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cart_servlet" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="productID" value="${p.id}">
                    <input type="submit" name="addToCart" value="Add to Cart">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```